# Installation process: Problem with partitions

Tags: system-installation

i want to install Ubuntu with an USB-stick. On the installion instructions on your Website it says, that at a certain point the window: Installion type should appear with three different Options. Those are: Install ubuntu alongside Windows 7, replace Windows 7 with Ubuntu, Something else. I have Windows 7 on my Laptop, but the installion type window only offers me two Options: Replace Windows 7 with ubuntu, Something else. The install ubuntu alongside Options does not appear. This is now my question: why not? what could i have done wrong?
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a single HDD in your PC? Have you re-sized your Windows partition, and left blank space - for example at the end of the partition - to allow for Ubuntu install?

To partition, you can use something like:

1) [EaseUS® Partition Master 9.2.2 Free Edition](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm)
or

2) [Paragon Partition Manager 2013 Free](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/pm-express/)

You do not need to make any partition, in the blank space, the Ubuntu installer will create all needed partitions for you (when selecting the option to install alongside of Windows).

.. make sure you've used a *correct* USB tool, like the [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/): so that the bootloader, actually Grub2 (and everything else), will install correctly.

**Edit**: Prior to partitioning, from within Windows, it may be a good idea to defragment the HDD, using a professional tool, in order arrange the data towards the beginning of the drive and avoid the partitioning tool having to move any files/data. I've been using [Raxco PerfectDisk](http://www.raxco.com/home/products/perfectdisk-pro) for years - on default settings - and find it pretty effective. It has a 30-day trial.